# How to solve the problem "The requested URL was not found on the server." Flask module?

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

I was starting to learn flask framework and I wrote some decorators and it was supposed that each decorator should show a certain function on the website but each time I run the code and write the route it shows me 404 Not Found error and shows me this message "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.".

This is the code:

```
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')

def root():
    return "This is not main directory"


@app.route('/potato')

def welcome():
    return "I like to eat potato"


@app.route('/yasso')

def yassin():
    return "Hello Yassin, sup man!!"


@app.route('/english')

def english():
    return "This is an english course"

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried to find solutions on Stackoverflow and there was an explanation that there are other older versions of the code that are actually running and the solution for this was to press Ctrl + Alt + Delete and press task manager and go to processes and shut down all processes named Python. I dont know exactly how to do it so can anyone explain the procedures step by step and if there is an another solution I would like to know it.

Note: When I ran the program first time it worked but when I changed words that are printed and ran again it returned the old statements that I wrote before.

Comment: are the blank lines between the decorator and the function a copy paste error or are they also in your code?

Comment: I left blank lines in between decorator and function to be easy to read. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get the otuput

```
 * Serving Flask app 'tmp'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

If I then go to http://127.0.0.1:5000, http://127.0.0.1:5000/potato and so on it also works fine.

The error you get suggest that the server is running correctly just that the URL you are trying to access does not exist. Since you have a `/` route just opening the url flask prints you should work.

Can you maybe update what is printed in your console when starting the server and what you input into your browser, maybe with a screenshot?

Also you should remove the blank lines between the decorator and the function. It is not wrong but a [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) violation and actually makes the code harder to read. A decorator is something strongly belonging to the function, class it is applied on. So there should be no blank line.